# Obtain address of just opened excel file via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a simple empty excel file and write a simple macro on workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
     MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

After opening the file and inserting new sheet in the excel file, the msgBox shows nothing. But after saving the file, the MsgBox shows correct address. Why is that?! How can I get the file address after the file is just opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because a newly created workbook doesn't have a path, yet!

once you save it, then it'll have a real path you can get

you could change your sub as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If ThisWorkbook.Path = "" Then '<--| if the workbook doesn't have path, yet
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) '<--| have the user choose a path and a name
            .Title = "Select Folder and name"
            .InitialFileName = "C:\"
            If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub '<--| if the user canceled the dialog box then exit sub
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs .SelectedItems(1), xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled '<--| otherwise save the workbook to the specified path as a macro enabled excel file
        End With
    End If
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path '<--| finally show the workbook path!
End Sub
```